# Some usernames appear as jumbled strings! YouTube API AuthSub

Tags: php, youtube-api, authsub

My website uses the YouTube API for users to interact. *Not all*, but a few usernames come into my system which are non-existant channels and I'm not sure how to detect this?

They are the correct length and I already check for alphanumeric strings only. An example:

> l3C9jpHV76COU9UHhWNneg

Here is the code snippet for getting the account username. Most of the time: there is no problem with this part of my code!

```
//User Profile Object
$userProfileEntry = $yt->getUserProfile('default');

//Get the username of the currently authed channel
$AuthedAccountName = (string)$userProfileEntry->getUsername();
```

Comment: This blog post explains what you're seeing: http://apiblog.youtube.com/2012/03/youtube-google-api-and-you.html

Comment: Ah! It all makes sense now! Thanks Jeff :)